# "This" selector not working, not even when put into $(document).ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I try to use $(body) it's not working as well, probably an easy fix I can't figure out.
But I've been trying for two hours now.

```html
<button onclick="bye()">Click me</button>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(
    function bye(){
        $(this).hide();
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use an "inline" event handler like `onclick="bye()"`, then the function you are calling needs to be defined in *global scope*. In your example you are passing the function as callback to `$(document).ready` instead, which is wrong for multiple reasons, but the function is definitely not defined in global scope.

You should just write

```js
// no $(document).ready here
function bye() {
  $(this).hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="bye()">Click me</button>
```

**However this will still not work!** Even though the function is now visible to the event handler, it will have the wrong `this` value when it is called. Since you are calling the function "normally" in your event handler (`bye()`), `this` will either be `undefined` or the global object (depending on strict mode).

In order for `this` to reference the button element, you have to change your event handler to `bye.call(this)` instead. `.call` will invoke the function and set the `this` value to the first argument. Inside the inline event handler, `this` refers to the button element:

```js
function bye() {
  $(this).hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="bye.call(this)">Click me</button>
<!--             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                -->
```

Alternatively, instead of using `this` inside `bye`, you can pass a reference to the element as argument to the event handler:

```js
function bye(element) {
//           ^^^^^^^
  $(element).hide();
//  ^^^^^^^
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="bye(this)">Click me</button>
<!--             ^^^^^^^^^                -->
```

---

Having said all this, there are more modern ways to bind event handlers than using inline event handlers. You can use jQuery to bind the event handler:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {         // once the DOM is loaded
  $('button').on('click', function() { // bind a click event handler
                                       // to every button element
    $(this).hide();                    // which hides the element
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
```